# How can a single CancellationTokenSource work for all methods in this scenario?

Tags: c#, async-await, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

I have a GUI application where the disconnect button needs to cancel async tasks and close the port.
So far, I can make it by using CancellationTokenSource at each method. The port should only be closed after the task is cancelled so the token is cancelled first, and then OperationCanceledException is caught inside the methods which in turn closes the port.

I declare at the very beginning:

```
private CancellationTokenSource my_cancelationTokenSource;
private CancellationTokenSource my_cancelationTokenSource_2;
private CancellationTokenSource my_cancelationTokenSource_3;
```

Then as an example I have the following three methods MyMethodAsync, MySecondMethodAsync and MyThirdMethodAsync:

```
private async Task MyMethodAsync(port)
{
    byte[] sent;

    my_cancelationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    try
    {
        do
        {
            await Task.Delay(period, my_cancelationTokenSource.Token);
            //some code here..
            byte[] received = await message.SendReceive(sent, my_cancelationTokenSource.Token);
            //some code here..

        }
        while (true);
    }

    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        try
        {
            my_cancelationTokenSource.Dispose();
            my_cancelationTokenSource = null;

            if (port.IsOpen)
            {
                port.Close();
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
}


private async Task MySecondMethodAsync(byte[] set)
{

    my_cancelationTokenSource_2 = new CancellationTokenSource();
   
   try
    {
            await Task.Delay(period, my_cancelationTokenSource_2.Token);
            //some code here
            bool check = await MyThirdMethod(set);
            //some code here
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        try
        {
            my_cancelationTokenSource_2.Dispose();
            my_cancelationTokenSource_2 = null;

            if (port.IsOpen)
            {
                port.Close();
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
}

private async Task MyThirdMethodAsync(byte[] set)
{

    my_cancelationTokenSource_3 = new CancellationTokenSource();
   
   try
    {
            await Task.Delay(period, my_cancelationTokenSource_3.Token);
            //some code here
            bool check = await MyThirdMethod(set);
            //some code here
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        try
        {
            my_cancelationTokenSource_3.Dispose();
            my_cancelationTokenSource_3 = null;

            if (port.IsOpen)
            {
                port.Close();
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

And here is the disconnect button event:

```
private void Button_Disconnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    my_cancelationTokenSource?.Cancel();
    my_cancelationTokenSource_2?.Cancel();
    my_cancelationTokenSource_3?.Cancel();

}
```

I will have tens of such methods like this and with this way I have to declare CancellationTokenSource for each method. How could the code be modified that one cancellation token for all methods can work for this case? Just declaring and using my_cancelationTokenSource for all methods.

Comment: So, use a single CTS? You'll want to instantiate it when the connection is formed (and the disconnect button becomes active) presumably, and you'll want to avoid disposing it (or probably even setting it to null) in each method

Comment: I couldn't manage to implement it by using a single cancelationTokenSource.

Comment: You're not really explaining why a single CTS doesn't work for you so hard to comment on what a good solution would be. However as a shot in the dark you have the ability to create linked CTS (so you can have 1 master that will cancel all children as well keep a child for every seperate method, keeping functionality to cancel specific ones without cancelling the rest). Take a look at `CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.createlinkedtokensource?view=net-5.0)

Comment: @pnatk It's hard for us to help with "couldn't manage". Could you post the code you tried, and the reason why it didn't work?

Comment: @Knoop My problem is I dont know how to implement it correctly. This is an area Im a bit scared.

Answer (score 3):

Use a single `CancellationTokenSource` and pass the **token** into each method. You should be cleaning up the port after any exception anyway, not just cancellation, so a finally will do fine.

You will need to handle / ignore the `OperationCancelledException` in whatever invokes the methods in the first place. (or you could eat it inside the function if the caller doesn't need to be aware of cancellation - difficult to advise without knowing how these are called)

```
private async Task MyMethodAsync(port, CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
    byte[] sent;

    try
    {
        do
        {
            await Task.Delay(period, cancelToken);
            //some code here..
            byte[] received = await message.SendReceive(sent, cancelToken);
            //some code here..

        }
        while (true);
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if (port.IsOpen)
            {
                port.Close();
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
}


private void Button_Disconnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    my_cancelationTokenSource.Cancel();
    my_cancelationTokenSource.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: In this case I need to declare at the very beginning like this as global variable?: CancellationTokenSource my_cancelationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

Comment: Yes, if it's only ever cancelled on shutdown, but I would assume t it would make sense to create it each time you connect?

Comment: I see you mean declare as global variable but create when connected?

Comment: You are also not disposing and nulling the TokenSource. Is it on purpose?

Comment: Yes, member variable (not global), create when needed, but it's very difficult to advise without knowing the flow of your app
Yes, you should dispose the source, my mistake there. nulling in not necessary if you recreate it each time you need it.

Comment: " nulling is not necessary if you recreate it each time" I see but in this case you are not creating CT each time. You only create once. Isnt it? In your MyMethodAsync you didnt create a CancellationTokenSource in that method for instance.

Comment: Each time you need it, not each time you call a method that consumes it. I don't know how your app works, but since you cancel when you disconnect, presumably you would create your cancelsource when you connect? All your methods then use that source token until you disconnect. If you reconnect you generate a new tokensource?

Comment: I was creating inside each method   my_cancelationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(); and  my_cancelationTokenSource_2 = new CancellationTokenSource(); so forth and so on. I want to correctly cancel all Tasks with a single disconnect button before the closing the port.. As you mentioned, I also think I might create one single CancelSource each time I connect. I was just not sure what nulling is doing and why some use it with question mark my_cancelationTokenSource?.Cancel(); checking whether it is null. I mean can you also say something about why nulling is not necessary in your case?

Comment: Again, it depends on how your app works. In my apps I structure them so that tokenSource can never be null. It's always created before it's required by anything else, so they never need to check for null. Some people set it back to null to indicate that it's been used and disposed, but to me that just adds noise and unnecessary code. Don't fret about it. If you find it easier to set to null and add nullchecks then do so.

Comment: The thing is, if I null my_cancelationTokenSource in  a task, I might get error when others receive cancellation request(since the common CTS already nulled)  because they share the same CTS. So maybe better not to null in your case. I will check it and try to give feedback soon.

Comment: Exactly how I predicted. I started to get a lot of errors already. It is not as easy as poeple think to implement safe robust code to make use of single token..

Comment: I get : 'The CancellationTokenSource has been disposed.' error when I click on disconnect button.

Comment: The error occurs at  await MyMethodAsync(port); which calls MyMethodAsync  inside connect button.

Comment: This is also cancelling at any button click now not only at disconnect button click. It doesnt work. I guess I will stick with my original way,

Answer (score 0):

> I will have tens of such methods like this and with this way I have to declare CancellationTokenSource for each method

I am not really sure what is the best way to manipulate cancellation tokens but this sounds more of like OOP problem. Instead of having multiple methods sharing the same logic you could make use of classes to reuse the shared logic. For example you can have a base class declaring some protected field of `CancellationTokenSource`, public method that would use that field and an abstract method that would do the specific work.

```
    public abstract class MyAsyncWorkerBase
    {
        protected CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        public void Cancel()
        {
            _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        }

        public async Task DoWork(IDontKnowTheType port)
        {
            try
            {
                await DoMySpecificWork(port);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                try
                {
                    _cancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
                    _cancellationTokenSource = null;

                    if (port.IsOpen)
                    {
                        port.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }

        protected abstract Task DoMySpecificWork(IDontKnowTheType port);
    }
```

then you can inherit your base class and just do your stuff in `DoMySpecificWork`.
I dont know your code base so my example is a little vague, you certainly can improve it. Also you can add some code to handle calling `DoWork` multiple times.
In the end you can put all your `MyAsyncWorkerBase` into some array for convenience and just loop through them in `Button_Disconnect_Click` and call `Cancel` on each.

Comment: Thanks. Could you also add how you would call/use it inside a method?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what exactly you want to call inside a method.
If you ask how overridden `DoMySpecificWork` should work - you just put your code there and pass `_cancellationTokenSource` where you need it (e.g. `message.SendReceive`)
If you ask how to use the class itself - hard to tell cause I dont know how rest of your code looks like =) The simplest way - you could create all your instances on the start and just call them in your button handlers (I assume, since its GUI app) simply like `await myWorker.DoWork(port)`

Comment: I meant you can use one of my methods MySecondMethod as an example to show how it is used there. Your way is interesting but I just need to be sure about the implementation.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a single `CancellationTokenSource` for all methods. To close the port you can simply [register](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.register?view=net-5.0) a callback on the cancellation token that will be notified when the token source is cancelled.

```
_cancellationTokenSource.Token.Register(() => 
                               {
                                   if(port.IsOpen)
                                   {
                                       port.Close();
                                   }
                               });
```

Comment: Will that code replace at each method              if (port.IsOpen)
            {
                port.Close();
            } ? Could you add more explicitly where it will be?

Comment: You don't specify the scope of `port`, I suppose it is a field on a class so it will replace the code on each method. Whenever the cancellation token source is cancelled it will close the port, so you can put this code where you create the port (if you have already access to the cancellation token) or when you create the cancellation token source.

Comment: You forgot to unregister. This piece of code is potential pit to out of memory exceptions. It will also need try{}catch{} block, because Unhandled exception will drop your app dead.

Comment: @eocron registration callbacks are kept by the cancellation token source and cleaned once the cts is cancelled or disposed. The risk is when the callback points to a reference that lives longer than the cts and the cts is not cleaned. About the exception, indeed we can wrap on a try/catch, for information callbacks are executed synchronously when the cts is cancelled, but I don't think it is a reason no to use it, it is similar for event handlers. A global handler at the app level can be used.

Comment: I think, you should point it out in your answer.